# RAD Studio Tokyo, cursor constantly spinning

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I am using RAD Studio 10.2.3 Tokyo.

The cursor in the IDE is constantly spinning when I write a `(`, or click with the mouse in the IDE, or press <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

This is happening only with C++Builder. I checked with Delphi and the problem does not seem to happen.

Sometimes, that spinning causes RAD Studio to completely close! I am then obliged to reopen the application and all my files!

This is a nightmare!

I checked different options in `Tools > Options > Editor Options`, but could not figure out what the problem is.

This is wasting me a lot of time when I am writing my code.

Does anybody know what is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

OK. I found the problem after many tests!
I was looking at the right place. But I was disabling the wrong option!
Issue mainly resolved, I can write my code without constant delays and application reboot!
What I did first was to disable the code completion. Because what was happening was like it was trying to retrieve something:

```
Tools > Options > Editor Options > Code Insight > Code Completion
```

But that was not the right option to disable. Then I disabled:

```
Tools > Options > Editor Options > Code Insight > Code parameters
Tools > Options > Editor Options > Code Insight > Tooltip expression evaluation
Tools > Options > Editor Options > Code Insight > Tooltip symbol Insight
```

Those options make the spinning and all the delays to stop. But sometimes it starts spinning again and then the application closes. I suppose that this part is another Rad studio bug I will have to live with!